# Proper data structure to store last n elements in C++

Tags: c++, data-structures

I need to store last n time values and I'm using a vector for this.  I can do this and it works, but my question is, at long run, the vector would fill up and I might run out of memory right?.  I'm using a stl vector of floats.

To be more clear : I'm pushing back time values from another process and i ONLY need the last 5 time values.

How can I do this efficiently, without letting the vector fill up and eventually run out of memory?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sounds as if you want a circular buffer that overrides the values.
Take a look at [boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/circular_buffer/doc/circular_buffer.html) for an example.

Answer (score 4):

To my knowledge, a queue (or deque) isn't circular in its memory usage. It will, instead, grow when needed and occassionally copy to fit.

I'd suggest making your own structure. All you need is an array of size 5, and a pointer (or index) for the 'last' item, which is going to be overwritten with the next new one. Each time a new value is added, the 'last' item is overwritten and the 'last' pointer is moved up:

```
last = (last+1)%5;
```

Make sure to find a good way to handle the start, where there are less than 5 items in the array. If you just fill the array with error/neutral values at the start, you should be okay.

Comment: That should be the selected answer IMHO. No std:: container offers any advantage over a plain C-style fixed-size array in that case. Unless you want to use external libraries like boost, that's the way to go.

Answer (score 3):

Use a [queue](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/queue.html) - it is perfect in that case. You push in the queue until it's size is 5 and then when adding a new value, you first pop from the queue and then push into it.

EDIT: if you need to be able to have direct access to all 5 elements probably a [deque](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/Deque.html) is a better option. I also believe the default queue implementation is based on deque.

Comment: Unless `n` is very large and the objects expensive to copy, `std::vector` will perform better than `std::deque`.

Comment: @JamesKanze what is your point here - why do you think so? We need to be able to add the objects to one end of the vector and remove objects from the other end. The deque is meant for such usage and I don't see a reason why vector would perform better.

Comment: @izomorphius But it does.  A much smaller constant factor for `std::vector` means that `std::deque` doesn't start performing better unless there are a lot of elements, or they are very expensive to copy.

Answer (score 0):

I think the STL queue is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Didnt remember the container name :)
I would use a std::queue container. So you can delete from the other end without worrying about positions within the sequence. About the threading thing... I think I cannot help but afaik vectors and list are not thread safe.

Answer (score 0):

I think the data should shift to the next place whenever a new data comes,
ie:

`4->5->6->7 //old data`

when a new data comes, the expected array must be

`5->6->7->8 //updated`
for that

```
int arr[4]={0};
int count=0;
int head=0;

void insert(int data)
{

    arr[count%4]=data;
    count++;
    if(count > 4)
        head=count%4;
    printf("count=%d head=%d\n",count,head);
}

void display()
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
        printf("%d->",arr[(head+i)%4]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int item_at(int i)
{
    return arr[(head+i)%4];
}

int main ()
{
    int opt,data;
    while(1)
    {
        printf("0. Exit\n1. Insert\n2. Display\n3. Item at\n");
        scanf("%d",&opt);
        if(opt == 0)
            return 0;
        else if(opt == 1)
        {
            scanf("%d",&data);
            insert(data);
        }
        else if(opt == 2)
        {
            display();
        }
        else if(opt == 3)
        {
            scanf("%d",&data);
            printf("arr[%d]=%d\n",data, item_at(data));
        }
    }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: ```if(count > 4)``` should be ```if(count >= 4)```. thanks for coming to my TED talk.